# Cannot Reassign SQL CommandText

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-ce

Why can't I do this? The method is called twice and the second time through the if statement is false however the original string assigned to the CommandText remains constant, even after I reassign it.

```
void someMethod(bool yes){

SqlCeCommand foo = new SqlCeCommand();
SqlCeCommand boo = new SqlCeCommand();

if(yes)
{
  foo.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM @where";
  boo.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM @where2";
  foo.Parameters.AddWithValue("@where", Earth);
  boo.Parameters.AddWithValue("@where2", Mars);

  addToDataBase(foo);
  addToDataBase(boo); 
}
else{
  foo.CommandText = "DELETE * FROM @where";
  boo.CommandText = "DELETE * FROM @where2";
  foo.Parameters.AddWithValue("@where", Earth);
  boo.Parameters.AddWithValue("@where2", Mars);

  deleteFromDataBase(foo);
  deleteFromDataBase(boo); 
}
```

the command text is not reassigned after the else statement

I can simply just restructure and make another sqlCeCommand, I just want to know why this doesn't work.

Thanks.

Comment: You can't use parameters to render the table name dynamic. (Neither the column names)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your command variable of type `SqlCeCommand`  is never reassigned. Because on each call you are creating a new object of this type. After this you make an assigned depending on whether your condition is met or not. If you wanna make a reassignment you have to declare your `SqlCeCommands` as private fields within your class.